# Помогите с префабами

Tags: unity3d

Помогите!В юнити ,в скрипте я должен в игровом процессе создать префаб,он создаётся,но создаётся не в том месте где я хочу(я имею ввиду не в том месте в иерархии).Например я хочу что бы префабы появлялись в канвасе,или в каком-то объекте,но префабы появляются сами по себе (в иерархии).Так вот,как сделать так чтобы префабы,создавались там ,где я хочу?

`void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
        switch (gameObject.name) {
        case "plus_square":
            var child = Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            child.SetParent (parent, false);
            break;
        }
    }`

Что не так?Переменные я объявил